# \lstlistoflistings remove indent in \documentclass{article}

Tags: listings, indentation, article

In my **\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}** I want to remove the indent of **\lstlistoflistings**.
There is a possibility like in the following to remove the indent for LOF and LOT. Is there something similar to remove it for Listings? If a MWE is necessary for the question, I will gladly do it.

```
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from figures in lof
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}


\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Code Listings}

\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from tables in lot
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following lines to the end of your preamble.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\l@lstlisting{1.5em}{0em}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\l@lstlisting{1.5em}{0em}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from figures in lof
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}


\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Code Listings}

\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from tables in lot
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing}]
(Listing content)
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Some table}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Some figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]